# How to exclusively select a radio button in two p:selectOneRadios

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, radio-button

**JSF 2.0,
Primefaces 3.1.1**

I have two p:selectOneRadio components:

```
   <p:selectOneRadio id="radio1" value="#{inningBean.lastDeliveryType}">  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Wide" itemValue="1" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="No Ball" itemValue="2" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Normal" itemValue="3" />
   </p:selectOneRadio> 

   <p:selectOneRadio id="radio2" value="#{inningBean.lastDeliveryRunsScored}">  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="2" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="3" itemValue="3" />
   </p:selectOneRadio>

   <p:commandButton />
```

I want that when user clicks the button, first radio button in each selectOneRadio is selected(Without submitting request to server). Just like user himself is selecting first radio button in each p:selectOneRadio, I just want to do it in javascript.

Comment: We need to program for it. One way is .. .. on selecting from first group, set the second group items to false using script. Another way is ... have another set of radio button to decide whether to enable the radio1 group or radio2 group for input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easily with jQuery. Take a look at these selectors:

- [input](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)
- [name](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)
- [first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

And on the [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function.

Now to the point :

For better manipulation with elements `ids` use `prependId="false"` on your `form` wrapping `p:selectOneRadio`s.

You don't want to reaload page so use `ajax="true"` in `p:commandButton`.

```
<p:commandButton value="select" ajax="true" onclick="selectRadios()" update="@form"/>
```

If you specify `id` for `p:selectOneRadio` primefaces will use it as `name` attribute for `input type="radio"` in rendered HTML page. Ofcourse if you don't use `prependId="false"` on the `form` element, primefaces will add `forms` `id` to the radio `name` attr., so it looks like `name="formId:radio1"`. With `prependId="false"` it's `name="radio1"`.

Now when you know that your radio buttons have specific `name` you can select **first** of each group specified by this `name` with simple function:

```
function selectRadios(){
               jQuery('input[name=radio1]:first').prop('checked', true);
               jQuery('input[name=radio2]:first').prop('checked', true);
            };
```

So the whole code looks like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function selectRadios(){
               jQuery('input[name=radio1]:first').prop('checked', true);
               jQuery('input[name=radio2]:first').prop('checked', true);
            };
</script>

<h:form id="formID" prependId="false">  
            <p:selectOneRadio id="radio1" value="#{testBean.radio1}">  
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Wide" itemValue="1" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="No Ball" itemValue="2" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Normal" itemValue="3" />
            </p:selectOneRadio> 

            <p:selectOneRadio  id="radio2" value="#{testBean.radio2}">  
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="2" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="3" itemValue="3" />
            </p:selectOneRadio>
            <p:commandButton value="select" ajax="true" onclick="selectRadios()" update="@form"/>
</h:form>
```

**Note** : You can also update each `p:selectOneRadio` separately if you don't want to update whole `form` by: `update="radio1 radio2"`

### EDIT

I don't know the way how you can select a `radio button` in primefaces (while using theme) without a `request` being made, because after clicking on `radio button` **GET** `request` will be made, in which related **UI icon** will be obtained (at least for the first click). If you are okay with that keep reading.

Since you don't want to make classic `HTTP request` nor `AJAX request` change the type of your `commandButton`:

```
<p:commandButton type="button" value="Default select" id="selButtonId" onclick="selectRadios();" />
```

And use this `js` function to trigger click on `radio button`:

```
function selectRadios(){
               jQuery('[for=radio1\\:0]').click();
               jQuery('[for=radio2\\:0]').click();
            };
```

`ID` of `radio button` will be used as `label` + *:x* , where *x* is the actual order number of the `button`. (0 being the first).
This is the proper way of using `click()` function, because you want to click on `label` instead on button **itself**, explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3077102/1317692).

**Note:** Primefaces ver 3.1.1 are bundled with jQuery ver 1.6.x which doesn't support [refresh method](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Button#method-refresh) of `button` element (it is supported since ver 1.8). Otherwise you could use :

```
  function selectRadios(){
       jQuery('input[name=radio1]:first').prop('checked', true).button("refresh");
       jQuery('input[name=radio2]:first').prop('checked', true).button("refresh");
    };
```

So IMHO what is written above is all you can do in your situation. I don't know if there is some alternative to `button` `refresh` method. Someone will correct me for sure if I'm wrong.

Regards

Comment: I dont want to submit request to server for just changing the selected radio, whether it is ajax or normal request

Comment: @djaqeel Edited to fit your requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. I will try that, and will get back to you. Please keep in touch,

Comment: are you a JSF expert or jQuery expert or both?

Comment: I'm just a passionate student of these 2, hopefully getting my BSc. title in 2 weeks :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working as a charm. I tried it as soon as you posted, and it was working. I was just waiting for a primefaces recommended solution. Because they are changing their library each and every day so who knows when they change their id assignment conventions..... But lets hope they dont mess with it in near future. :)

Comment: how to do this with p:selectOneButton? could you please help with this?